# Get the UTF-8 code of a character in Python or shell

Tags: python, bash, zsh

How can I get the <strike>UTF-8 code</strike>  **Unicode code point** <sup>1</sup> of any single character in Python or in the shell?

I’d like to have (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Character_codes) for distinguishing between "plus" and "full plus" signs):

```py
getUTF8('＋')
> U+FF0B
```

```py
getUTF8('+')
> U+002B
```

---

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Character_codes) Correct terminology, as per the comments.

Comment: NB. the format is a bit different in the duplicate but the logic is the same, please let me know if you think this is not a duplicate

Comment: The point is the format !  It might be difficult to relate `b'\\u3232'`with its UTF-code syntax. I think this isn’t a duplicate.

Comment: @kotchwane reopened, but what is you problem since you provided a solution?

Comment: Terminology notice: It seems that whatever you are looking for, it is not UTF-8, which is a variable-length encoding. For example, the "full plus" sign would be 3 bytes (EF BC 8B) in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 3):

Using `bash`, `zsh` or `ksh93` with a UTF-8 aware locale:

```sh
$ printf "U+%04X\n" "'＋" "'+"
U+FF0B
U+002B
```

When their builtin versions of `printf(1)` see a numeric format specifier (Like `%X`), and the first character of the relevant argument (After the usual shell wordsplitting and parsing) is a double or single quote, the next character's codepoint value is taken as the argument, instead of the character itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a Python version:

```py
def code_point(c):
   return "U+{:04X}".format(ord(c))
```

With above example:

```py
for c in ['＋', '+']:
   print(code_point(c))

> U+FF0B
> U+002B
```

Comment: That's not 'the UTF-8 code', that's the unicode code point!

Comment: You can also use just `"U+{:04X}".format(ord(c))`. Note the X instead of x.

Comment: @Sören : Right, but note that the OP meanwhile changed his mind and wants to have a code point.

Comment: @user1934428 I didn’t change my mind, I just wasn’t familiar with the correct terminology. I think the examples given in my question showed without ambiguity what I was trying to achieve.